Did Luke and others mentioned in the book of Acts use notes, an itinerary or diary from Antioch?
In watching a Youtube video on Dating Acts, by David Litwa some interesting points were raised (3 minutes in) as a response to Carl Armstrong's defense of a traditional dating and authorship of Acts.
What is a general survey of Christian thoughts on whether the apostolic team mentioned in Acts 27 used notes, an itinerary or a diary of sorts? If so, what sort of methods might Luke have used to save his notes as he swam ashore from the shipwreck described in Acts 27:44?

For that person who voted to close the question, what can be done to fix this question to fit into the guidelines better?
